# Python error handling and starts the while loop over again

Tags: python

I am trying to comment my instagram post with python to practice my self. So, I am trying to write 20 comments not matter what but after some time an exception rises and I would like to refhresh the page to start the loop over again. I am able to write some posts but when the exception rises my page is refreshing infinite times. May you know how can I refresh the page 1 time and starts the loop over again?

```
comments=0

while comments < 20:

    while True:
        try:

            commentbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').click()                                
            sleep(4)

            writepost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').send_keys('my text')
            sleep(5)

            submitpost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').click()                                          
            sleep(5)

            writesecondpost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').send_keys('my text')
            sleep(5)

            submitpost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').click()                                          
            sleep(5)
            comments+=1
            sleep(4)
        except Exception as e:
            driver.refresh()
            sleep(4)
            pass
```

Comment: move `driver.refresh(); sleep(4)` out from exception. just `break` under execption.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

For example something like that?

except Exception as e:
            break
            driver.refresh()

Comment: The `<20` in 'while comments < 20:' doesn't have any effect because you have put an infinite loop (while True) inside it

Comment: I have inserted commnets+=1

Comment: Its still refreshing the website infinitive times

Comment: What is the exception that is raised?

Comment: After some time/posts my instagram stucks, so I would like to refresh the page and to continue the loop. the exception raised is NoSuchElement but I think that I can avoid it. My problem is with the driver.refresh () which runs invinitive times and does not start the loop over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it a bit more complex than it needs to.

As JeffUK pointed out, you should try to avoid those nested loops.

Additionally, you wouldn't want to do too much complex stuff when handling exceptions. Remember that these are supposed to stop your code because there was an error, they are not simply "obstacles" to negotiate and move past by.

When handling exceptions, you should try to avoid having more exceptions by further adding instructions because you're in a different scope of the program. Python can handle this, but it can make debugging way harder than it's supposed to.

Note that in the `except` clause, you're not changing the precondition for none of the loops (you're not increasing the comments nor changing the `True` in `while True`.

When working with web scraping packages, it's hard enough to deal with asynchronicity (waiting for stuff to render). So try to KISS (Keep it super simple).

So, let's redo your code:

```
def post_comment(driver):

    try:
        commentbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').click()                                
        sleep(4)
        writepost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').send_keys('my text')
        sleep(5)
        submitpost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').click()                                          
        sleep(5)
        writesecondpost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').send_keys('my text')
        sleep(5)
        submitpost = driver.find_element_by_xpath('my xpath').click()                                          
        sleep(5)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # It's good practice to try and print exceptions
        return False # Just fail the subroutine if it wasn't succesful!

comments = 0

# We assume 'driver' is well defined

while comments < 20:
    
    new_comment_posted = post_comment(driver)
    
    if new_comment_posted:   # This condition was missing, you were using the try block in its place, but handling boolean values is easier than handling exceptions.
        comments += 1
    else: 
        driver.refresh()
        sleep(4)
        # Still, this will go on forever until there are 20 comments, but this is what you want, right?
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your effort. Actually, your programm makes the same mistake as mine. It keeps refreshing the page when reaches at the else statement. 
What I would like is when the program reaches at the else statement to start the try statement over again

Comment: Then you should see whether the execution gets stuck at `driver.refresh()` or not. Try adding prints before and after that line and see where the problem is. If it's not going past `driver.refresh()`, the problem lies within your framework or browser. Else, the error should be clear enough.